# Can i put my shortcode inside a variable in php files?

Tags: php, functions

for example something like that

```
 <?php $check_in = [st_custom_meta key="st_custom_available_dates"] ; ?>
```

i do not know if i use this the right way or if this is even possible..

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/), as in:

```
$check_in = do_shortcode ('[st_custom_meta key="st_custom_available_dates"]') ;
```